# Inner h2 needs to be 100% height

Tags: html, css, drupal

I'm building my first drupal website and I have some CSS problems, since the html cannot be changed. I reckon it's a small adjustment I need to make, but I don't see it... I want link-tag to have 100% width and height, so that you see the blog-item detail-page whenever you click the container (and not only the title or read more-link)

I've simplified the Drupal code. I've also created a small [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5HNF/1/)

### HTML

```
<div class="node-blog-entry" id="node-10">
  <h2><a href="/drupal/blog/2nd-blog-item">2nd blog item</a></h2>

  <div class="submitted">          
    <span>Submitted by root on 20 November, 2013 - 19:43</span>    
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="field-name-body">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">            
          <p>blablablab</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <ul class="links inline">
    <li class="node-readmore first last"><a href="">Read more</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.node-blog-entry
{
margin-bottom: 15px;
width: 100%;
max-height: 9999px;
padding: 3% 0;
background-color: lightblue;
}
.node-blog-entry:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,1);
}
.node-blog-entry > *
{
padding:0 3%;
}
.node-blog-entry h2
{
display:block;
background-color: grey;
width: 94%;
min-height: 94%;
color: rgba(68,68,68,1);
}
.node-readmore
{
list-style:none;
float:right;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
HS.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the h2 to reach the top? If so, its a matter off removing paddings and margins.

Comment: In order to make the entire blog-entry clickable, I want the h2 (and also the link that's within it) to have 100% width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `position:absolute` and making the full container his relative parent:

```
.node-readmore {
  list-style:none;
  float:right;
}

.node-blog-entry {
  position:relative;
 }
.node-blog-entry .node-readmore a{
  position:absolute;
  text-align:right;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

An example here **http://jsfiddle.net/Y5HNF/4/**

The problem here is that you compromise the position for the text on the `a` tag. You can fix it using other properties like `box-sizing` and `padding`.